# Perl script (api) not returning the data fetched from mysql to html

Tags: html, perl, xmlhttprequest

I have this html that posts name of an artist to an api that I wrote in Perl which queries mysql database and outputs the result. I can post the artist to api and also the api grabs the data from database but its not diplaying the data back to my html page. Could you guys please help?
HTML script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
print <<ENDTAG

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
<body>
  <form>
  </form>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput()
        {
        var artist = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
        console.log(artist);
        var api = "http://api/post";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", api, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/text; charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('x-auth-token', 'ooooo');
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                console.log('readyStatechange:  ' + xmlhttp.readyState);

                 if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
                        {

                        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = response;
                        }
                else
                        {

                    //alert ("Something Went Wrong");
                     // console.error(xmlhttp.status);
                        }
        }
        console.log('Before open: ' + xmlhttp.readyState);

        xmlhttp.send(artist);

}
  </script>
</body>

<form method="POST" action="">
<label><b>Enter Artist</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>
<input type="submit" onclick="showInput();">
<br>
<label>Your input: </label>
<p><span id="display"></span></p>

</html>
ENDTAG
```

The perl api returned following :

```
Opened database successfully
ARTIST is : john denver
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Content-Type: text/html

<p>The database contains the following:</p>
<table cols=3 border=1>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Album</th>
</tr><tr>
<td>Downhill Stuff</td>
<td>1979</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Dreamland Express</td>
<td>1985</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Love Is The Master</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Windsong</td>
<td>1975</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Catch Another Butterfly</td>
<td>1969</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Cowboy's Delight</td>
<td>1975</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>How Can I Leave You Again</td>
<td>1977</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Love Again</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sail Away Home</td>
<td>1970</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sweet Melinda</td>
<td>1979</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Daydream</td>
<td>1969</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gimme Your Love</td>
<td>1985</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hold On Tightly</td>
<td>1234</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>I Can't Escape</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>It's A Possibility</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Let Us Begin (What Are We Maki</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Love Again</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Love Is The Master</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>One World</td>
<td>1986</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>To The Wild Country</td>
<td>1977</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Dreams</td>
<td>1982</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Forest Lawn</td>
<td>1970</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Got My Heart Set On You</td>
<td>1985</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tradewinds</td>
<td>1977</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Circus</td>
<td>1969</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Eagles & Horses</td>
<td>1990</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Flight (The Higher We Fly)</td>
<td>1983</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Life Is So Good</td>
<td>1979</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>The Ballad Of St. Anne's Reel</td>
<td>1980</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hold On To Me</td>
<td>1991</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>The Harder They Fall</td>
<td>1985</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What One Man Can Do</td>
<td>1982</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Johnny B. Goode</td>
<td>1979</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Shanghai Breezes</td>
<td>1982</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Take Me Home, Country Roads</td>
<td>1971</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Wrangell Mountain Song</td>
<td>1980</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A Wild Heart Looking For A Home</td>
<td>1985</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Wild Montana Skies</td>
<td>1983</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Heart To Heart</td>
<td>1982</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Relatively Speaking</td>
<td>1982</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gospel Changes</td>
<td>1971</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Around And Around</td>
<td>1971</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Druthers</td>
<td>1977</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Garden Song</td>
<td>1979</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

I did look around for similar posts and I did find some but couldnt figure out where Im going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your code and found that you made a number of mistakes: in form itself and submission part (`onsubmi=....`), in javascript processing submission (was corrected - `return false`, please adjust **api** to your server).

I did not replicate database but used my own script with your data from the table, you will find it bellow.

I hope that you will find it useful, although I think that **AJAX** would be a better option

Main file with perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

print <<ENDTAG
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  </head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function showInput()
            {
                var artist = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
                console.log(artist);
                //alert(artist);
                var api = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/api_perl.pl";
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("POST", api, true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/text; charset=UTF-8");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('x-auth-token', 'ooooo');
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    console.log('readyStatechange:  ' + xmlhttp.readyState);

                    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
                    {
                        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = response;
                    } else {
                        //alert ("Something Went Wrong");
                        //console.error(xmlhttp.status);
                    }
                }
                console.log('Before open: ' + xmlhttp.readyState);

                xmlhttp.send(artist);
                return false;
        }
        </script>

        <form method="POST" onsubmit="return showInput();">
            <label><b>Enter Artist</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <br>
        <label>Your input: </label>
        <p><span id="display"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
ENDTAG
```

File `api_perl.pl`

```
##!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say "Content-Type: text/html\n";

say "
<p>The database contains the following:</p>
<table cols=3 border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Album</th>
    </tr>
";

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;
    chomp;
    my($song,$year,$album) = split ',';
    say "<tr><td>$song</td><td>$year</td><td>$album</td></tr>";
}
say "
</table>
";

__DATA__
Downhill Stuff,1979,Album 1
Dreamland Express,1985,Album 2
Love Is The Master,1986,Album 1
Windsong,1975,Album 1
Catch Another Butterfly,1969,Album 2
Cowboy's Delight,1975,Album 1
How Can I Leave You Again,1977,Album 1
Love Again,1986,Album 1
Sail Away Home,1970,Album 1
Sweet Melinda,1979,Album 1
Daydream,1969,Album 1
Gimme Your Love,1985,Album 1
Hold On Tightly,1234,Album 1
I Can't Escape,1986,Album 1
It's A Possibility,1986,Album 1
Let Us Begin (What Are We Maki),1986,Album 1
Love Again,1986,Album 1
Love Is The Master,1986,Album 1
One World,1986,Album 1
To The Wild Country,1977,Album 1
Dreams,1982,Album 1
Forest Lawn,1970,Album 1
Got My Heart Set On You,1985,Album 1
Tradewinds,1977,Album 1
Circus,1969,Album 1
Eagles & Horses,1990,Album 1
Flight (The Higher We Fly),1983,Album 1
Life Is So Good,1979,Album 1
The Ballad Of St. Anne's Reel,1980,Album 1
Hold On To Me,1991,Album 1
The Harder They Fall,1985,Album 1
What One Man Can Do,1982,Album 1
Johnny B. Goode,1979,Album 1
Shanghai Breezes,1982,Album 1
Take Me Home - Country Roads,1971,Album 1
Wrangell Mountain Song,1980,Album 1
A Wild Heart Looking For A Home,1985,Album 1
Wild Montana Skies,1983,Album 1
Heart To Heart,1982,Album 1
Relatively Speaking,1982,Album 1
Gospel Changes,1971,Album 1
Around And Around,1971,Album 1
Druthers,1977,Album 1
Garden Song,1979,Album 1
```

File `styles.css` (put into root web directory or edit `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/styles.css'>` and point **href** to proper location of `styles.css` file -- edit main perl file with form)

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help, im still unable to get any display back to the html(perl in this case after using your code). However, Im still at it. 
I dont know AJAX though.

Comment: @dbnoob -- you can start to learn AJAX by visiting [website](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp). I tested the code with following [package](https://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) installed in Windows 10 (laptop). The packages [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) has Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl, TomCat, Mercury, FileZilla.

Comment: @dbnoob -- Have you edited `var api = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/api_perl.pl";` to point proper location of your perl api script? Did you try to run your script by pointing your web browser to api script? Did perl api script produced expected output in the web browser window?